# In the movie "Good Time", why did the protagonists do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, good-time

In the Safdie Brothers' film *Good Time*, the main characters rob a bank. They pass a note to the teller, demanding just $65,000. My question is twofold:

1. Why did they rob the bank?
2. Why did they demand a weirdly specific, yet small amount of money?

Comment: [Why does anyone rob a bank?](https://www.fbi.gov/history/famous-cases/willie-sutton#:~:text=he%20robbed%20banks%20%E2%80%9C-,because%20that%E2%80%99s%20where%20the%20money%20is,-%E2%80%9D%20was%20one%20of)